# Can we find a pair of symmetric absolutely continuous measures on a measurable space?

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ and $(X,\mathcal{B},\nu)$ be measure spaces.

Can we find a pair of measures $\nu$ and $\mu$ on $(X,\mathcal{B})$ such that $ \nu << \mu \implies \mu << \nu$, where $ \nu << \mu$ denotes $\nu(E)=0$ whenever $\mu(E)=0$ for any $E \in \mathcal{B}$ i.e. $\nu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$ ?

Comment: Positive multiple of the Lebesgue measure for example...

Comment: More generally, if $f \ge 0$ is $\mu$-integrable on $X$, then $\nu(E) = \int_E f~d\mu$ should be absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$, and if $f > 0$, then the opposite should be true as well.